# Why ConstraintLayout 1.1.0 layout_constraintWidth_percent and layout_constraintDimensionRatio cannot work together?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to use layout_constraintDimensionRatio and layout_constraintWidth_percent attribute together in an ImageView, but I find that they cannot be able to work together.

My xml code is:

### 1.using layout_constraintWidth_percent only:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

its corresponding UI is:
[layout_constraintWidth_percent_only.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2Soq.png)

### 2.using layout_constraintWidth_percent and layout_constraintDimensionRatio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,2:1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

its corresponding UI is:
[layout_constraintWidth_percent_and_layout_constraintDimensionRatio.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afA3z.png)

It's clear that when I use layout_constraintDimensionRatio, layout_constraintWidth_percent does not work.

What I really want is the width of the ImageView is 50% of its parent, and then the height of the ImageView is 50% of its width by using layout_constraintWidth_percent and layout_constraintDimensionRatio together.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `android:layout_height="0dp"` to match constraint should help you achieve the desired result.

According to the documentation:

> You can also use ratio if both dimensions are set to MATCH_CONSTRAINT (0dp). In this case the system sets the largest dimensions the satisfies all constraints and maintains the aspect ratio specified.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

**Edit** It seems `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent` does not provide actual horizontal constraints by itself to the `View` so the following will behave differently (first on has the `right` horizontal constraint set and the second does not):

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,2:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

and

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,2:1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

We are constraining the width based as percentage of the parent and then constraining the height based on width by using `H` in `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,2:1"`. In the first case the view does not show and in the second it does in fact display correctly. It looks like if you want to use `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent` you need to add both horizontal constraints and then you can correctly constrain height based on width.

As the alternative to this approach you can use `Guideline` set at 50% of parent width to constrain your `ImageView` and then constrain height according to the ratio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,2:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your approach really works. One more question, why do you change app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,2:1"  to app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:1"?

Comment: Well, something the matter happens when I change  app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:1" to app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="3:2"? I donnot know how to paste the pic. Shame on me. Could you please help me out?

Comment: I realized there are some problems with it and did some more testing. I updated my answer.

Comment: Your answer really makes sense.